# Implementing oauth in SugarCRM using .NET

Tags: php, asp.net, oauth, sugarcrm

I have a web application developed in .net framework. I am trying to implement Oauth in sugarCRM  in order to integrate it with my applications.

The Oauth mechanism given by sugarCRM is using PHP     [Click Here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/06_Oauth)...
where as, my application is designed in ASP.

I am trying to figure out solution (like converting php code to asp or implementing the same mechanism in my application) for same but got no solution.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using this library http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ to replicate the OAuth functionality.

Comment: earlier i tried using same.approach used for sugarCRM is different than dotnetopenauth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after much pain, I've got my .Net Code working on SugarCRM.....

This is what I did....all in a Console app for me.  This a proof of concept and so everthing is hard coded for now!

Use Nuget to Install OAuth by Daniel Crenna

### Step 1: Establish Consumer Key

Go into Admin -> OAuth Keys section on SugarCRM and create a new record, I used Key & Secret.

### Step 2: Creating a Request Token

```
private static void CreateRequestToken()
{
    // Creating a new instance directly
    OAuthRequest client = new OAuthRequest
    {
        Method = "GET",
        Type = OAuthRequestType.RequestToken,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ConsumerKey = "Key",
        ConsumerSecret = "Secret",
        RequestUrl = "http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php",
        Version = "1.0",
        SignatureTreatment = OAuthSignatureTreatment.Escaped
    };

    // Using URL query authorization
    string auth = client.GetAuthorizationQuery(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "method", "oauth_request_token" } });

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php?method=oauth_request_token&" + auth);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    NameValueCollection query;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(result);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(query["authorize_url"]);
    Console.WriteLine(query["oauth_token"]);
    Console.WriteLine(query["oauth_token_secret"]);
}
```

This is the tricky part that took me ages to figure out, notice the requesturl is without the query part in the client, and you have add it to the GetAuthorizationQuery call AND to the actual WebRequest url.

Note down the 3 items ready for Step 4.

### Step 3 Approve Request Token

Visit the url "authorize_url" above and also add &token= "oauth_token".  For this was:

```
http://localhost/index.php?module=OAuthTokens&action=authorize&token=adae15a306b5
```

Authorise the token and record the Token Authorisation Code.

### Step 4 Request Access Token

```
private static void RequestAccessToken()
{
    OAuthRequest client = new OAuthRequest
    {
        Method = "GET",
        Type = OAuthRequestType.AccessToken,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ConsumerKey = "Key",
        ConsumerSecret = "Secret",
        RequestUrl = "http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php",
        Version = "1.0",
        SignatureTreatment = OAuthSignatureTreatment.Escaped,
        Token = "adae15a306b5",
        TokenSecret = "e1f47d2a9e72",
        Verifier = "33e2e437b2b3"
    };

    // Using URL query authorization
   string auth = client.GetAuthorizationQuery(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "method", "oauth_access_token" } });

   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php?method=oauth_access_token&" + auth);
   var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

   NameValueCollection query;
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
       string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
       query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(result);
   }

   Console.WriteLine(query["oauth_token"]);
   Console.WriteLine(query["oauth_token_secret"]);
}
```

Token and TokenSecret are from Step 2, Verifier is the Auth Code from Step 3.

### Step 5 Use the Access Token

I'm just using the session id as Recommended by the Documentation, so to get the sessionId

```
private static void GetSessionId()
{
    OAuthRequest client = new OAuthRequest
    {
        Method = "GET",
        Type = OAuthRequestType.ProtectedResource,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ConsumerKey = "Key",
        ConsumerSecret = "Secret",
        RequestUrl = "http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php",
        Version = "1.0",
        SignatureTreatment = OAuthSignatureTreatment.Escaped,
        Token = "adae15a306b5",
        TokenSecret = "2d68ecf5152f"
     };

     string auth = client.GetAuthorizationQuery(new Dictionary<string, string>() 
     { 
        { "method", "oauth_access" }, 
        { "input_type", "JSON" },
        { "request_type", "JSON" },
        { "response_type", "JSON" } 
     });

     var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php?method=oauth_access&input_type=JSON&request_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&" + auth);
     var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

     dynamic o;
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
     {
         string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
         o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("SessionId: {0}", o.id);
}
```

Here I'm using JSON.Net to parse the Json into a dynamic object for easy access to the id.

### Step 6 Make it do something....

Over to you!

Pretty painful experience, but at least its working for me.....

Tim

Comment: thanks tim,Ill give it a try and let you know about it? and how to do you sync the activities from your project to sugarCRM(i mean accessing methods).in my case,i want to add the contacts to sugarCRM when i add them in my module.

Comment: Tim, can you please help me on this to be implemented in Java.?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about Java.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get what you meant by implementing in SugarCRM way. But if you can't use **dotnetopenauth**, you can spin your own OAuth using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) or [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault/tree/master/hammock/src)

Comment: Did you saw the link i mentioned in my question? method used for auth is different for sugarcrm than traditional one. i would have used dotnetopenauth if it would have supported the approach used for normal auth.

Comment: The hammock link is dead.

Comment: @RohnAdams Thanks. Fixed the link.